# Django 3.0 tutorial - mysite/URL not working

Tags: django

I have completed all seven steps of the [Writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) tutorial for 3.0. Everything works great, *except* the **base site URL for 'mysite'** at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. At the beginning of the tutorial, it worked, but it stopped working as I progressed/at the end. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` works fine. Can anyone tell me what I'm  doing wrong?

Based on how the tutorial is structured, i.e. "add this and that and this and that," etc., that I overwrote something.

**Here is the error I'm receiving in my browser:**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    polls/
    admin/

The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

**Here is the error I'm receiving in Terminal:**

```
Not Found: /
[20/Jun/2020 11:01:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2027
```

**Here is my polls/urls.py file:**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**Here is my mysite/urls.py file:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Here is TEMPLATES in mysite/settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**SOLVED/ANSWER added from comments:**

Answer from expert [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem)

**1. Edit mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('polls.urls')),  # no /polls/ prefix
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**2. Run `python manage.py runserver`**

Comment: The path should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls` since you wrote `path('polls/', include('polls.urls'))`, all urls are prefixed with `polls/`

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

All your paths for the poll app are here prefixed by `polls/`, since you wrote:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

You thus can visit the `IndexView` by fetching the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/` URI. If you do not want to prefix the urls, you can rewrite the root `urls.py` to:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('polls.urls')),  # no /polls/ prefix
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Then you can simply visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.

Comment: Ah! Makes sense by fetching the http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/. However, I am still receiving the error after updating (and applying all possible migrations?) to mysite/urls.py: **path('', include('polls.urls')),** - any ideas?

Comment: @tucktuck9: no you don't need to migrate, since this has nothing to do with the database. Exactly *what* error do you get?

Comment: Good to know migrations are only for DB changes. I'm getting the same error: **[20/Jun/2020 12:21:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2027**. `
Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    polls/
    admin/

The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
`

Comment: @tucktuck9: but did you change `path(..)` to `path('', ...)` in the root url for `polls.urls`? Looks like that did not happen? Did you *restart* the server? Perhaps removed the Python cache files (`*.pyc`).

Comment: Sorry, I did not restart the server. This did it! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me.